# Renamed an icloud drive folder with the .tmp extension and files have disappeared

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, icloud, finder, folders

I read that I could rename a folder to have the..tmp extension to prevent it syncing over. I did this to a folder that had some confidential files, but I renamed the folder in my icloud drive and the files have all disappeared.

I found a copy of the folder on the desktop, but that was also empty. Any idea where I could locate these files or are they lost?

Answer (score 0):

You try to restore previous files on iCloud.com:

- First, in iCloud.com > iCloud Drive, check if the files are present in the iCloud.com web view. If they are present here, download a copy first and foremost - and then you can decide how to proceed once you've secured a copy.
- If that doesn't work, then again in iCloud.com > iCloud Drive, click "recently deleted" in the bottom right hand corner.
- If neither of these work, you can try reaching out to Apple - they may be able to restore an account-level backup if the files are especially important.

Comment: The files may exist and be manageable in icloud.com. I found that icloud.com was perfectly happy to let me create and manage a folder named `tmp`. But renaming a folder to `tmp` caused it to disappear from the Files app in iOS. So, you can simply use icloud.com to rename it to something other than `tmp` (or other than `«something».tmp`) and it should reappear on your iOS devices.